# Selecting full names of pairs of ISO-coded countries

Tags: sql, inner-join

Suppose I have got two tables, one of which is named A and contains two columns : country1 (as an ISO code), country2 (as an ISO code) whilst the other one is named B and contains two columns : code (ISO code of country) and name (full name of country).

I would like to list all pairs of countries that occur in table A using their full names, rather than their ISO codes.

If I had to get the full name of every country that occurs in the first column of table A, I would write te following:

```
SELECT name AS name1
FROM B
    INNER JOIN A ON B.code = A.country1
```

However, I am struggling to find out how to get both columns with full names.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: so u have countrycodes in different columns in tablea?

Comment: Instead of prose, I'd suggest you provide the SQL statements to set up the tables and add some example data. Then, based on that very example data, provide the expected output data.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to join the `code` column from B on both the `country1` and `country2` columns from A. You just need to make sure you alias it differently on each join.

```
SELECT A.country1, A.country2, B1.name AS name1, B2.name as name2
FROM A
JOIN B AS B1 ON B1.code = A.country1
JOIN B AS B2 ON B2.code = A.country2
```

Answer (score 0):

Join should always be on same column type from both tables. `Isnull` will work for you, If country codes are stored in different columns in TableA

```
SELECT name AS name1
FROM B
    INNER JOIN A ON B.code = isnull(A.country1, a.Country2)
```

or Use case statement

```
   SELECT name AS name1
    FROM B
        INNER JOIN A ON B.code = case when A.country1 is null then A.country2 
                                   else A.country1 end
```

Comment: There is no column named code in table A. 'A.code' doesn't seem to make sense .